# Create table using text file bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server from a text file using bulk insert but I keep getting bulk load data conversion error(truncation). Is there something I'm doing wrong? The top part is how the data is in the text and below is the code.

```
'01','INPATIENT FACILITY','010','ACUTE CARE HOSPITAL'
'01','INPATIENT FACILITY','011','PRIVATE PSYCHIATRIC HOSPITAL'
'01','INPATIENT FACILITY','012','INPATIENT MEDICAL REHAB HOSPITAL'

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROVIDER_TYPE]
(
    [PROVIDER_TYPE_ID] [VARCHAR](2) NULL,
    [PROVIDER_TYPE] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [PROVIDER_SPECIALITY_ID] [VARCHAR](3) NULL,
    [PROVIDER_SPECIALITY] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

BULK INSERT DBO.PROVIDER_TYPE FROM 'C:\SQL\t2.txt'
WITH (
    datafiletype = 'char'
    ,fieldterminator = ','
    ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value isn't 2 characters long, it's 4. The value is `'01'`; that's **inclusive** of the single quotes (`'`). This is why you're getting a truncation error, as `'01'` (`'''01'''` if you were to want to represent the string in T-SQL) doesn't fit in a `varchar(2)`.

If you're on SQL Server 2017+ you can use the `FORMAT` and `FIELDQUOTE` options. Note that I also use `\r\n` for `ROWTERMINATOR`, as I had both when I created the file, if yours only contains a line break (and no carriage return), then just use `\n`:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.PROVIDER_TYPE FROM '/mnt/WDBlue/t2.txt' --This was my test file
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
      FORMAT = 'CSV',
      FIELDQUOTE = '''');
```

If you aren't using SQL Server 2017+, then it simply does not support quoted fields, and I suggest using a different tool.

Comment: Worked. Thank you!